# Store output of xref-find-apropos in a variable within elisp code

Tags: lsp, xref, ccls

Is it possible to extract the results returned by xref-find-apropos to a variable within elisp code? In particular, I want to get all files names where the found symbol occurs.

So what I want is something like

```
(let ((results (xref-find-apropos "Symbol")))
  (print (filenames results)))
```

Or maybe there is a way to achieve this in a different way? I need to access a list of files in my workspace where the given symbol occurs.

I am using ccls as my backend for xref.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can ask for references from the LSP backend directly:

```
(lsp-request "workspace/symbol" `(:query ,symbol))
```

This returns a hashmap I can further parse and find locations by looking at 'uri' keys.

Comment: Ah okay nice. I now notice that I did not fully read your question, while the first sentence says 'results returned by xref-find-apropos to a variable within elisp code'. Therefore, I thought that you wanted to search for emacs-lisp symbols. Anyway, you have found a nice solution!

Answer (score 1):

By inspecting the `xref-find-apropos` -> `xref--find-xrefs` -> `xref--create-fetcher` functions, we find that `xref-backend-apropos` is the working horse.
Calling that function with the appropriate arguments, we find that it returns a list of [structures](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/cl/Structures.html). Finally, we find that we can achieve what you ask for, using:

```lisp
(defun my-xref-get-files (pattern)
  (let* ((results (xref-backend-apropos (xref-find-backend) pattern))
         (locations (mapcar #'xref-item-location results)))
    (mapcar #'xref-elisp-location-file locations)))

(setq results (my-xref-get-files "Symbol"))
```

Comment: Somehow this works in a buffer with elisp code, but when I try to run this from a buffer with C++ code, I am getting an error: `Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument xref-elisp-location #<xref-file-location xref-file-location-1579c70b6870>)
  signal(wrong-type-argument (xref-elisp-location #<xref-file-location xref-file-location-1579c70b6870>))` Sorry if my question wasn't very clear, I am trying to find locations of symbols from C++ code. I posted a solution that works for me below.

Comment: Looks like the call to xref-backend-apropos returns xref-item, which can be further analyzed to access xref-file-location. We simply need to replace xref-elisp-location with xref-file-location. I upvoted your answer too, thank you.